# Next JS i18Next build serverSideTranslations error

Tags: reactjs, next.js, i18next, next-i18next

I am trying to build my react NEXT JS application, but after I run

> npm run build

I am getting this error:

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/it/landing". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error: next-i18next was unable to find a user config
. . . 
Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /it/landing
```

I tried removing serverSideTranslations method from the getStaticProps function inside the landing/index.tsx

which look like this

```
export const getStaticProps = async ({ locale }) => {  
  
  return {
    props: {
      ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, [
        "notifier",
        "home",
      ])),
    }
  }
}
```

After I commented the code in serverSideTranslations, the app builds properly.

I also have another page which contains both getStaticPaths and getStaticProps, but it is working fine, with no errors.

```
// register/[encoded].tsx
export const getStaticProps = async ({ locale }) => {  
  return {
    props: {
      ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, [
        "notifier"
      ])),
    }
  }
}
```

I am new in react and next js developement so maybe I am missing something, but it look like a strange behaviour.

The code works if I run

> npm run dev

Comment: Did you find a way to make it works ? As you getStaticProps make the build fail.

Comment: I think I found the solution for me. The problem was in my next.config.js. I replaced "module.exports= withImages(i18n)" with "module.exports= withImages({i18n})" The {} were missing.